# blog tag produces error right after if statement

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to render three columns for per row in my html file by using **Django2.1** and **Bootstrap4**.

*The piece of HTML code looks like following:*

```
    <main class="container" role="main">
        {% for treasure in treasures %}
            {% block row %}

            <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
                <div class="card card-body h-100">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{ treasure.name }} </h4>
                    <img class="card-img-bottom mw-100 mh-100" src="{{ treasure.img_url }}" alt="A Kind of Treasure">
                </div>
            </div>

            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                {% endblock %} {% block row %}
            {% endif %}

            {% endblock %}
        {% endfor %}
    </main>
```

*The error I get is:*

> Invalid block tag on line 44: 'endblock', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

PS: Line 44 is `{% endblock %} {% block row %}`, so I get the error right after the `if` check. If I delete that line, it does not produce any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `{% endblock %}` tag is overlapping with the `{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}` tag.

You are basically doing the following:

```
    {% block row %}
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
    {% endblock %} 

    {% block row %}
{% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Your `if` tag and `endif` tag are in two separate `blocks`, this is causing the error. You wil have to remove the `block` tags between the `if` tags.

Comment: I get the point but then how can I render three cols per row?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, you can rename your blocks, and for clarity, add the name in the `endblock` tag.

```
      {% for treasure in treasures %}
        {% block row %}

        ...

            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}

                {% block row2 %} 
                {% endblock row2 %} # add the name in endblock for clarity

            {% endif %}

        {% endblock row %} # add the name in endblock for clarity

    {% endfor %}
```